# unique constraint on a set

Tags: sql-server, database-design, relational-theory

With reference to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2678807/unique-constraint-w-o-trigger-on-one-to-many-relation), what would be a correct way to implement **Unique tag Combination Constraint** in SQL Server 2005?

To illustrate the problem, I make an example:

A tag_bundle consists of one or more than one tags.
  A unique tag combination can map to a unique tag_bundle, vice versa.

```
 tag_bundle                   tag            tag_bundle_relation
 +---------------+        +--------+      +---------------+--------+
 | tag_bundle_id |        | tag_id |      | tag_bundle_id | tag_id |
 +---------------+        +--------+      +---------------+--------+
 |       1       |        | 100    |      |       1       |  100   |
 +---------------+        +--------+      +---------------+--------+
 |       2       |        | 101    |      |       1       |  101   |
 +---------------+        +--------+      +---------------+--------+ 
                          | 102    |      |       2       |  101   |
                          +--------+      +---------------+--------+  
                                          |       2       |  102   |
                                          +---------------+--------+
```

There can't be another tag_bundle having exactly the same combination from tag 100 and tag 101.
There can't be another tag_bundle having exactly the same combination from tag 101 and tag 102.

How can I ensure such unique constraint when executing SQL **"concurrently"**!! 
that is, to prevent **concurrently** adding two bundles with exactly **the same** tag combination

Adding a simple unique constraint on any table does not work,
Is there any solution other than Trigger or explicit lock.

I come to only this simple way: make tag combination into string, and let it be a unique column.

```
tag_bundle  (unique on tags)         tag            tag_bundle_relation
 +---------------+-----------+      +--------+      +---------------+--------+
 | tag_bundle_id |  tags     |      | tag_id |      | tag_bundle_id | tag_id |
 +---------------+-----------+      +--------+      +---------------+--------+
 |       1       | "100,101" |      | 101    |      |       1       |  101   |
 +---------------+-----------+      +--------+      +---------------+--------+
                                    | 100    |      |       1       |  100   |
                                    +--------+      +---------------+--------+
```

but it seems not a good way :(

Is there no other solution but with triggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My only suggestion is to create stored procedure that performs DML on `tag_bundle_relation` and restrict all users from manipulating the table directly (it's in a sense 'explicit lock' as you say).  I don't see any other acceptable ways to enforce the required restriction. In my understanding your simple solution just adds complexity to the system - you will need more triggers to synchronize `tags` field with `tag_bundle_relation` and `tag` tables. Also, you may get false fail if you are adding records to `tag_bundle_relation` one by one - for instance, inserting `tag_bundle_id=3` with `tag_id`s 100,101,102 will fail after attempting to insert 101 (assuming 100 already inserted).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How would you ensure Unique Sets of Tags for each Tag_Bundle_Id in the Stored Procedure? Thanks,

Comment: @mxasim : I'd probably write a stored procedure that accepts table parameter `create type TP_tag_bundle_param as table(tag_bundle_id int not null, tag_id int not null, primary key (tag_bundle_id, tag_id))`, then in the body I need to make sure I don't have exactly the same tag_id s associated with another bundle (various methods, using `join` or `exist`/`not exist`). That's just a general approach I'd take; it's definitely needs refining and more thinking.